# Amazon EC2 AMI Root Authorized_keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, authorized-keys

I'm working with the public RedHat AMI on EC2, and am trying to create an image that by default allows `ssh` for root. I changed the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file so that `PermitRootLogin` is set to `yes`, and changed `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` so that the file starts with `ssh-rsa` instead of:

```
no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ec2-user\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10".
```

After I do this, I am able to ssh into my instance as root, but when I create a custom AMI from this instance, the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file reverts back to the old version that disallows it.

I was wondering how to make it so that my custom AMI has root ssh enabled by default, or if there's a file somewhere that is changing root's authorized_key file back to the original that I can edit.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why the file is being reverted, but as an aside I suggest you use 'PermitRootLogin without-password' rather than 'PermitRootLogin yes' if you have to allow root access. Despite what it appears to say, 'without-password' means "only allow logins with a key, but not with passwords". This should keep the script kiddies from getting access if the root password is set and they manage to brute force it.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen similar things happen with Ubuntu/Debian AMIs.

The most likely culprit is [cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

In our case, adjusting `disable_root: true` => `disable_root: false` in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` did the trick.